# CSS- Hyphens Not working in chrome and firefox

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to use CSS Hyphens. I've used `-webkit-hyphens: auto;` , `overflow-wrap:hyphenate.`, `-moz-hyphens: auto;` but nothing happens in result.

[image]

How can successfully be been able to implement hyphenation?

Comment: Hyphenation support in browsers is spotty. There are lots of questions on SO about that. Search for them. Bottom line is, you cannot depend on this.

Comment: `.class {
 -ms-word-break: break-all;
     word-break: break-all;

     // Non standard for webkit
     word-break: break-word;

-webkit-hyphens: auto;
   -moz-hyphens: auto;
        hyphens: auto;
}`

Comment: ^ this and more on [hyphens](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/h/hyphenate/)

Comment: In some browsers, it only works if you specify the language explicitly. https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/m2ws1aru/2/ For other browsers, we may just have to wait until they have caught up with the specs. Workaround: insert &#173;s manually.

Answer (score 0):

The standardized syntax is now :

```
hyphens:auto;
```

But it works on few browsers.

You can also use entity `&shy;` where you want to cut the words.
But it's a long and tedious job.